# XSLT code returns empty rows when converting XML to HTML table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert an XML document to HTML using XSLT 1.0. I aim to display the XML rows in an HTML table. But my XSLT code returns empty rows in the HTML table. Here's what my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<people>
    <person id="ABCDE1234" firstname="John" lastname="Lewis" sex="male"/>
    <person id="XYZWU6789" firstname="Marie" lastname="Claire" sex="female"/>
</people>
```

Here's my XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>XML to HTML using XSLT</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table border="1" >
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>firstname</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
            <th>sex</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="people/person">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sex"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, my XSLT code runs properly when I reformat the XML file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<people>    
    <person>
        <id>ABCDE1234</id>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <lastname>Lewis</lastname>
        <sex>Male</sex>
    </person>

    <person>
        <id>XYZWU6789</id>
        <firstname>Mary</firstname>
        <lastname>Claire</lastname>
        <sex>Female</sex>
    </person>
</people>
```

Why is this happening? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `@` sign so that the values will recognize as attributes.

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@firstname"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@lastname"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@sex"/></td>
```

Comment: Works. Thanks :)